PDF spec and PADES, adding images after signing to the document without invalidating previous signatures

I have a PADES document that was digitally signed with a certification signature. Also a DocMDP was added with level 2 (form filling and signing) permissions.
Additional signers can sign the pdf and fill out form fields by adding text to the /V row in the field dictionary without invalidating the initial digital signature.
My prob is how do i add (or can i add?) images to these fields, so for example, when an additional signee signs can i add a QR code to a field? I've tried adding an image to the widget annotation of the field after signing but it invalidates the original signature, as seen below.. this was a text-field though.. ive seen some mention of using a push-button field?
Below is what chatgpt come back with but it didn't work for me. What acroform field dictionary values can i change apart from /V ? or can i stream data into the /V field?

Key Concepts for Adding Images Post-Signing

    1.  Incremental Updates:
    •   PAdES-compliant signatures ensure that the original signed content remains untouched.
    •   Any modifications, such as adding an image, must be added as incremental changes outside the signed portion.
    2.  Editable Fields:
    •   Ensure the form field where the image is to be added is explicitly excluded from the signature’s locking mechanism.
    3.  DocMDP Permissions:
    •   The document should be signed with DocMDP Level 2 or Level 3, which allows form filling and modifications to specific fields.

require 'hexapdf'

def add_image_to_field(signed_pdf, output_pdf, field_name, image_path)
  # Open the signed PDF
  doc = HexaPDF::Document.open(signed_pdf)

  # Find the form field
  field = doc.acro_form.field_by_name(field_name)
  raise "Field '#{field_name}' not found" if field.nil?

  # Get the field's widget annotation
  widget = field.widget
  rect = widget[:Rect]

  # Add the image to the field's location
  page = widget.page
  x1, y1, x2, y2 = rect
  image = doc.images.add(File.open(image_path, 'rb'))
  canvas = page.canvas
  canvas.image(image, at: [x1, y1], width: x2 - x1, height: y2 - y1)

  # Save as incremental update
  doc.write(output_pdf, incremental: true)
  puts "Image added to field '#{field_name}' in #{output_pdf}"
end

# Example usage
signed_pdf = 'signed_document.pdf' # Input signed PDF
output_pdf = 'signed_with_image.pdf' # Output with added image
field_name = 'ImageField' # The name of the form field
image_path = 'image_to_add.jpg' # Path to the image

add_image_to_field(signed_pdf, output_pdf, field_name, image_path)


Explanation

    1.  Open the Signed PDF:
    •   Use HexaPDF to open the document without altering the signed content.
    2.  Locate the Field:
    •   Use acro_form.field_by_name to find the form field where the image should be added.
    3.  Insert the Image:
    •   Place the image at the field’s coordinates using the page canvas.
    4.  Incremental Save:
    •   Save the PDF as an incremental update to maintain the integrity of the existing signature.

Prerequisites for Success

    •   Field Setup:
    •   The field (ImageField) must have been configured before signing and excluded from the signature’s lock.
    •   DocMDP:
    •   Ensure the document was signed with appropriate permissions (e.g., Level 2 or 3).




Can you share the PDF file for analysis? I don't know HexaPDF (and, therefore, cannot comment on your code) but an analysis of the file may make clear why "1 Page(s) Modified" is reported. Concerning which field widgets you can use to hold images... PDF does not have genuine image fields, so strictly speaking: None. Well, ok, signature fields allow arbitrary appearances, so you can add an image while signing there. And Acrobat abuses pushbuttons with some JavaScript as image fields, so maybe Acrobat permits pushbutton appearance changes as "image field fill-in". Other validators possibly not

Thanks for commenting @mlk. Yep the PDF above doesnt work as i changed the widget annotation after to test and it invalidated the certification sig, so i didnt post the pdf as i know it doesn't work now... Do you know what i can change on a field? Apart from the /V param? can you change the /AP flag? without invalidating the docmdp form filling? or can you stream images into the /V flag, maybe its not possible to add an image after the certificate signature for a 2nd signer

"Do you know what i can change on a field?" - Form fill-in means both setting the value (V) and updating the appearance (AP) to show the new value. So yes, you are allowed to change field widgets appearances whenever form fill-in is allowed. BUT validators may check whether the value somehow matches the appearance, and except signature fields and possibly push buttons, there is no field type whose appearance may contain an image.
